# What are the different hasta (hand-postures) which Sri Vishnu holds in temples?

Tags: vishnu, temple

Sri Maha Vishnu resides as Archa-avatara murti (idol form) in many temples throughout Bharata, especially in 108 Divya Desas, most of which are in Tamil Nadu.

There is a sthala purana (story) behind each temple, why Bhagavan came down to that particular place, to give darshan to which rishi, to fulfill what boon or lift what curse etc.

In addition, He also holds a particular posture of his right and left hands e.g. Abhaya Hasta (fear not), Varada Hasta (boon) etc.

What are all the different hastas, along with an image depicting it, and their meaning and significance ?